# Получить данные из input и обработать их

Tags: javascript, input, link, html-form

Друзья, доброго дня. Очень нужна Ваша помощь. Я только начал изучение js и много еще путаю и не вижу. Прошу помочь разобраться со следующей ситуацией и сильно не пинать :)

И так, имеется 3 импута - Фамилия, Имя, Отчество. Эти импуты имеют три версии самих себя же, вся разница лишь в ссылках страниц.

Необходимо получить часть urla и создать условие, при котором будет проверяться полученный кусок урла с вариантами, что у меня имеются (вот как выглядит нужный кусок урла ?type=1),а затем получить значения, что введет пользователь в эти импуты.

После этого их необходимо подставить в форму, что я приведу ниже. После этого необходимо энкодить полученную строку и сделать из всего этого ссылку по шаблону.

У меня имеется версия этого решения на PHP, но нужно перевести все это дело в JS

И так, вот отрывок версии на PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['search_button'])) {
    //проверяем есть ли в урле ?type=1
    if($type==1){

// создаем переменную и передаем в нее ФИО из полей ввода "input"

        $google_query1="(\"{$_POST['surname']} {$_POST['name']} {$_POST['otchestvo']}\") & ((site:adress1.ru) OR (site:adress2.ru) OR (site:adress3.ru) OR (site:adress4.net) OR (site:adress5.com) OR (site:adress6.ru) OR (site:adress7.ru) OR (site:adress8.ru) OR (site:adress9.org) OR (site:adress10.ru) OR (site:adress11.ru) OR (site:adress12.net) OR (site:adress13.kz) OR (site:adress14.ru) OR (site:adress15.ru))";
        $google_query2="(\"{$_POST['surname']} {$_POST['name']} {$_POST['otchestvo']}\") & ( \"параметр1\" OR \"параметр2\" OR \"параметр3\" OR \"параметр4\" OR \"параметр5\" OR \"параметр6\" OR \"параметр7\" OR \"параметр8\")";

// энкодим полученный массив 

        $google_query1=urlencode($google_query1);
        $google_query2=urlencode($google_query2);


// делаем ссылку для перехода.

$websearch_queries['fl_FIO_soc_google']="https://www.google.ru/?gws_rd=ssl#q= {$google_query1}&newwindow=1&start=50";
$websearch_queries['fl_FIO_google']="https://www.google.ru/?gws_rd=ssl#q= {$google_query2}&newwindow=1&start=50";
```

Вот пример наших imput'ов:

```
<input style="width:100%;" type="text" name="surname" id="surname" value="">
<input style="width:100%;" type="text" name="name" id="name" value="">
<input style="width:100%;" type="text" name="otchestvo" id="otchestvo" value="">
```

Вот пример того, как я это вижу, но не могу реализовать(написал как посчитал правильным, поправьте пожалуйста, если ошибаюсь):

```
// получаем часть строки из url'a и записываем ее в "searchAdress"
var searchAdress = location.search;

// создаем переменную "url" и передаем ей значение "searchAdress"
var url = searchAdress; 

// создаем переменную "lastName" и записываем в нее значение Фамилии
var lastName = $('#surname ').val();

// создаем переменную "firstName" и записываем в нее значение имени
var firstName = $('#name ').val();

// создаем переменную "middleName" и записываем в нее значение отчества
var middleName = $('#otchestvo ').val();

// создаем начальное условие
if( 'url' == '?type=1' ) {

// создаем переменную и передаем в нее ФИО из полей ввода "input"
<code>тут какая-то магия, до которой я не додумался пока</code>

//создаем новую переменную. добавляем полученные данные из инпутов к общей формуле для поисковика и превращаем в одну цельную ссылку.

$google_query1="(\"{$_POST['surname']} {$_POST['name']} {$_POST['otchestvo']}\") & ((site:adress1.ru) OR (site:adress2.ru) OR (site:adress3.ru) OR (site:adress4.net) OR (site:adress5.com) OR (site:adress6.ru) OR (site:adress7.ru) OR (site:adress8.ru) OR (site:adress9.org) OR (site:adress10.ru) OR (site:adress11.ru) OR (site:adress12.net) OR (site:adress13.kz) OR (site:adress14.ru) OR (site:adress15.ru))";

$google_query2="(\"{$_POST['surname']} {$_POST['name']} {$_POST['otchestvo']}\") & ( \"параметр1\" OR \"параметр2\" OR \"параметр3\" OR \"параметр4\" OR \"параметр5\" OR \"параметр6\" OR \"параметр7\" OR \"параметр8\")";

//открываем все полученные ссылки в новом окне
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('a'), function (link) {
  window.open(link.href);});
return false;
```

В общем прошу Вашей помощи друзья. Я понимаю, что мною написанное - дебри...но все же помогите разобраться. Заранее спасибо!

P.S. Если упростить все выше написанное до более понятного, пошагового алгоритма, то будет как-то так:

1. Нужно получить часть url и сделать проверку на соответствие полученного куска одному из трех условий.

получаю часть url таким образом:

```
var searchAdress = location.search;
var url = searchAdress;
```

2. Далее получаю введенные данные из инпутов.
3. Создаем условие на соответствие одному из трех вариантов, а именно (далее прилагаю полученные части из url):

?type=1
?type=2
?type=3

Если я все правильно сделал, то выглядит это так

```
if( 'url' == '?type=1' ) {}
```

4. Генерируем ссылку, для перехода в поисковик вот по такой логике:

   ("Фамилия Имя Отчество") & ((site:adress1.ru) OR (site:adress2.ru) OR (site:adress3.ru) OR (site:adress4.net) OR (site:adress5.com) OR (site:adress6.ru) OR (site:adress7.ru) OR (site:adress8.ru) OR (site:adress9.org) OR (site:adress10.ru) OR (site:adress11.ru) OR (site:adress12.net) OR (site:adress13.kz) OR (site:adress14.ru) OR (site:adress15.ru))
5. Открываем полученную(ые) ссылку(и) в новом окне.

Comment: при котором будет проверяться полученный кусок урла  - откуда мы его получаем? Я так понимаю нам с какой то страницы отправляются данные методом post?

Comment: получаем со страницы, на которой заполняются формы. Их три. Они фиксированные. У каждой есть свое значение в урле - "?type=X"

Answer (score 1):

Ребят, всем спасибо - решение нашел сам. Оставлю его тут, на случай, если кому понадобится реализовать нечто схожее.

```
// получаем часть строки из url'a (?type=X) и записываем ее в "searchAdress"
var searchAdress = location.search;

// создаем переменную "url" и передаем ей значение "searchAdress"
var url = searchAdress;

// создаем переменную "lastName" и записываем в нее значение Фамилии из input
var lastName = $('#surname ').val();

// создаем переменную "firstName" и записываем в нее значение имени из input
var firstName = $('#name ').val();

// создаем переменную "middleName" и записываем в нее значение отчества из input
var middleName = $('#otchestvo ').val();

// создаем начальное условие
if (url === '?type=1') {

var google_query1 = "(" + lastName + " " + firstName + " " + middleName + ") & ((site:adress1.ru) OR (site:adress2.ru) OR (site:adress3.ru) OR (site:adress4.net) OR (site:adress5.com) OR (site:adress6.ru) OR (site:adress7.ru) OR (site:adress8.ru) OR (site:adress9.org) OR (site:adress10.ru) OR (site:adress11.ru) OR (site:adress12.net) OR (site:adress13.kz) OR (site:adress14.ru) OR (site:adress15.ru))";

var google_query2 = "(" + lastName + " " + firstName + " " + middleName + ") & ( \"параметр1\" OR \"параметр2\" OR \"параметр3\" OR \"параметр4\" OR \"параметр5\" OR \"параметр6\" OR \"параметр7\" OR \"параметр8\")";


// энкодим полученный массив 

google_query1 = encodeURIComponent(google_query1);
google_query2 = encodeURIComponent(google_query2);


// делаем ссылку для перехода.

var websearch_queries1 = "https://www.google.ru/?gws_rd=ssl#q= " + google_query1 + " &newwindow=1&start=0";
var websearch_queries2 = "https://www.google.ru/?gws_rd=ssl#q= " + google_query2 + " &newwindow=1&start=0";

//создаем объект из ссылок
$(document).ready(function () {
var link_massiv = {"fl_FIO_soc_google": websearch_queries1,
                   "fl_FIO_google": websearch_queries2};

//выводим список ul>li из массива "link_massiv" в таблицу с id="takeLink"
    var ul = document.createElement('ul');
    for (elem in link_massiv) {
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        if(!(link_massiv[elem])) continue;
        $(a).appendTo(li);
        $(a).attr('href', link_massiv[elem]);
        $(a).text(elem);
        $(a).addClass("linkback");
        $(li).appendTo(ul);
    }

    $("#takeLink").html($(ul).html());
```

Кнопку на раскрытие всех сгенеренных ссылок сделаю позже - это не проблема. А если кому потребуется что-то схожее, думаю смогут сделать ее самостоятельно. Всем спасибо!